# Missing ansible_uptime_seconds variable

Tags: ansible

When I run this playbook, its not finding `ansible_uptime_seconds`  variable. But `ansible hostname -m setup` gives this variable. I am using `ansible 2.9.23` version.

```
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Print all available facts
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: ansible_facts
```

Getting this message

```
'ansible_uptime_seconds' is undefined
```

How to get this value in the play book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact name is `uptime_seconds`, when `facts` are collected without `setup` module. however its `"ansible_uptime_seconds"` when collected with `setup` module.

```
---

- name: Sample playbook
  connection: local
  #  gather_facts: false
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: print uptime sec
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts.uptime_seconds }}"
```

Output of the above playbook is:

```
PLAY [Sample playbook] *********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]
TASK [print uptime sec] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "172603"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: `gather_subset:
    - hardware`
 did the trick. Thanks

Comment: If you had to do this, this mean you have limited the subset automatically gathered in playbook in your ansible.cfg (or even that you disabled facts gatehering by default). This is something missing in you question.

Comment: I see , I had `#gather_subset = all` in my vm